# What do RssAnon, RssFile and RssShmem on Linux mean?

Tags: linux, memory

As I understand, on Linux the output of /proc/(pid)/status gives you the following numbers, which add up to the "VmRSS" (resident set size):

```
VmRSS:     11060 kB
RssAnon:        4644 kB
RssFile:        6416 kB
RssShmem:          0 kB
```

The man page for proc has:

```
* RssAnon: Size of resident anonymous memory.  (since Linux 4.5).

* RssFile: Size of resident file mappings.  (since Linux 4.5).

* RssShmem: Size of resident shared memory (includes System V shared memory, mappings
                from tmpfs(5), and shared anonymous mappings).  (since Linux 4.5).
```

I'm still a little unclear what these numbers correspond to. Some questions:

- What is "anonymous memory?"
- What is a "resident file mapping?"
- Which of these are backed by physical RAM - all of them? I understand RssFile is referring to memory mapped files - is it the size of the mapped files on the filesystem, or a cost in RAM?

Comment: See section Linux Memory Types of "top" man page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html